# Is there a way to make selenium webdriver screenshot an entire page?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The title is pretty self explanatory. I have a page with an iframe and two columns (left and right)

Left has no scroll bar, while right has a scroll bar with a total of 600px to scroll. I need to screenshot the entirety of the right hand column. It doesn't matter if I get the entire page or not, as long as everything in the right hand column is in the screenshot.

I am using Selenium 2 Webdriver + python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is workaround by following the steps described in http://www.ramandv.com/blog/angularjs-protractor-selenium-headless-end-end-testing/ and create a gaint virtual display for running your program.